# How to correctly execute SQL script in C# and rollback if it fails?

Tags: c#, sql-server, transactions

I have some SQL scripts and I need to execute it on a database.

I need to execute the whole script and if there is any error, I need to rollback everything from that script.

The solution would be to wrap the whole script in a transaction - but how to do it if there are "nested" transactions in that script? Because if I get it right, no nested transactions exist in MS SQL server and first commit/rollback inside the script destroys my "outer" transaction.

Comment: if youre loading your sql script into a string before you execute it, manipulate the string so you comment out all the BEGIN TRANSACTION calls

Comment: @CaiusJard this would work, but the script can be really long - is it the only way to do this?

Comment: Nested transactions are not real, but they *are* effectively faked. The first `COMMIT` will *not* commit the whole thing; that won't happen until the last `COMMIT` (which will be your outer transaction). A `ROLLBACK` will make it impossible to commit any more, but that's a matter of handling the resulting error properly. Do note that if you have a truly *arbitrary* script, you can run into problems with statements that cannot be run in any transaction, external or otherwise (like `CREATE DATABASE`).

Comment: @kacka I'm not sure `strSql = strSql.Replace("BEGIN TRANSACTION", "--BEGIN TRANSACTION").Replace("COMMIT TRANSACTION", "--COMMIT TRANSACTION")` cares how long the script is

Comment: Why do you need to nest transactions? You sound like you were onto it then, you are using all of the right terms and know you're looking to transaction rollback - think you're over-complicating it.

Comment: @JᴀʏMᴇᴇ well because I need to execute some scripts, but I want to commit only if they don't fail....but if someone deals with transactions inside that script, it brokes my code

Comment: I don't understand the idea of transactions inside the script though, why would that be the case?

Comment: Also, supposing there were nested transactions, and one of those _did_ in fact rollback - the desired behaviour should  be that _your_ parent transaction also rolls back, since something inside of that didn't complete successfully. It feels to me like you don't have a problem here.

Comment: @CaiusJard - that is a horribly hacky solution. That's a band-aid approach to a design flaw.

Comment: True; I'm approaching it from the viewpoint though that the OP has no control over the presence of these statements